# template does not exist in django

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 2.2 and I'm getting

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/

This is the traceback that I got:

```
Environment:`


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:2000/register/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'post.apps.PostConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/blog/templates/signup.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/signup.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/signup.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/blog/post/templates/signup.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback:

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/blog/blog/views.py" in register
  21.     return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  19.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/
Exception Value: signup.html
```

And this is the structure of project:

```
blog
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
├── settings.py
├── templates
│   └── signup.html
├── urls.py
├── views.py
└── wsgi.py
```

(there is an app called post that I don't think you need the structure of it. But if it's needed I'll share it.)

As you can see template is in the right place that django engine looks for but it says "source does not exist".

views.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py file:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'post.apps.PostConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

P.S. 1) This is the code that I cloned from github ([repository](https://github.com/imanaspaul/django-blog-basic/archive/master.zip)) and it's from [this](https://manascode.com/how-to-add-authentication-or-registration-system-in-django-blog-part-2/) site's tutorial.
2) I've tried this with django 3 either but the same problem happened.

Comment: Show the settings and view

Comment: In the error output you can see the files tried to lead. The first one (`/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/blog/templates/signup.html`) seems to match your structure. Can you verify the file exists at **exactly** that path?

Comment: @unknown I've added views.py and settings.py files.

Comment: @KlausD. Exactly. I see that it says it's there but I still get this error

Comment: Dont you need to add your blog app to your `installed_apps`?

Comment: @devdob blog is the project's name not an app.

Comment: Its an app. The main app of your "blog project"

Comment: @devdob Got that. but is there a problem?

Comment: What does `stat /home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/manascode/part1/django-blog-basic-master/blog/templates/signup.html` on your system shell return?

Comment: That gave me 'no such file or directory' but it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the project. If blog is the project name, then it should have the main app name blog. I think you are showing that project structure.

You might create template folder in blog project, not in blog main app.

What you have to do?

Either:

```
Just cut paste your template folder outside the blog app and inside blog project folder.
```

Or:

```
return render(request, 'blog/signup.html', {'form': form}) and create a blog named folder in templates and place signup.html inside that.
```

Correct me if I am wrong.